# Argparse is not recognizing the only positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

Argparse is not recognizing my positional argument. Here's the setup:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("url")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--username")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--password")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--depth", default=sys.maxsize)
parser.add_argument("-t", "--threads", default=4)
```

At the bottom, i have this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print sys.argv
        args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)
        if args.username is not None and args.password is not None:
            auth = [args.username, args.password]
        else:
            auth = None

        spider(args.url,
               basic_auth=auth,
               threads=int(args.threads),
               depth=int(args.depth))
    else:
        parser.print_help()  # Handle 0 command-line arguments
```

When i call my script on the command line like `staunch$ ./spiderer.py http://www.example.com/`, i get this:

```
usage: spiderer.py [-h] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [-d DEPTH] [-t THREADS]
                   url
spiderer.py: error: unrecognized arguments: http://www.example.com/
```

I tried adding `nargs=1` to the url `add_argument`, but that didn't work. Neither does calling `./spiderer.py` with all of the other arguments specified. What's goin' on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you change

```
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)
```

to

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Otherwise `parse_args` will read `sys.argv[0]` (the name of your program) as the positional argument, and then `sys.argv[1]` will be an unexpected second positional argument.

You could alternatively call:

```
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

if you prefer.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you.

Comment: Although not directly, the default value of the argument to `parse_args` is, in fact, `sys.argv[1:]`.